# Micro Snap to an anchor point

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I´m trying to make a scroll snap to an anchor when this anchor is almost in the right position. I´m saying that because I don´t want all those scripts that take me directly to the anchor while I'm still far away from it. I don´t want the user to loose control of the scrolling unless its almost there. I just want to perfectly fit a div on the users screen.

For example, if my anchor is on the 2000th pixel of the page, i want it to snap to 2000px when the scroll is between 1990px and 2010px. If not, it should not snap and should react just if the user scrolls up or down manually the page.

So you guys visualize any script/solution to this? Better if it's handled only with CSS but it's ok if js is needed.

Thanks!

Comment: I added tags for visiblity.

Answer (score 0):

The [scroll-snap-type and scroll-snap-align](https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/) CSS rules that allows you to do so. You can see a sample here: https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/wvWvKVv. The libraries loaded are optional. The polyfill will make it work on older versions of IE.

---

On the other hand, if you want a simpler solution you could implement your own algorithm. Breaking down the process what we need is to:

1. Detect when the user has stopped scrolling.
2. If user has stopped scrolling then check if we are near an anchor.
3. If we are near an anchor then snap to it.

This would do it:

```js
const snapAt = 1000
const snapRange = 50

// Setup isScrolling variable
var isScrolling;

// Listen for scroll events
window.addEventListener('scroll', function ( event ) {
  console.log("Current scroll is: ", window.scrollY)
    // Clear our timeout throughout the scroll
    window.clearTimeout( isScrolling );
    // Set a timeout to run after scrolling ends
    isScrolling = setTimeout(function() {
        // Run the callback
        console.log("Scrolling has stopped at:", window.scrollY);
    if (window.scrollY >= (snapAt - snapRange) && window.scrollY <= (snapAt + snapRange)) {
      console.log("---We fall into the snap range. Snapping.---")
      window.scrollTo(0, snapAt)
    }
    
    }, 250);
}, false);
```

```html
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
<h1>snap at 1000</h1>
```

And it basically snaps at `snapAt` if the current scroll falls into `snapRange`.